# Google App Engine 413 error (Request Entity Too Large)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, http-status-code-413

I've implemented an app engine server in Python for processing html documents sent to it. It's all well and good when I run it locally, but when running off the App engine, I get the following error:

"413. That’s an error. Your client issued a request that was too large. That’s all we know."

The request is only 155KB, and I thought the app engine request limit was 10MB. I've verified that I haven't exceeded any of the daily quotas, so anyone know what might be going on?

Thanks in advance!

-Saswat

Comment: Do you know what line is throwing that error? If not put in a few logging.logs and narrow down which call is throwing that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like it was because I was making a GET request. Changing it to POST fixed it.