# Request too large error making a request to App Engine

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, python-requests

I have an app on App Engine Flex using the Python 3 runtime.  I get the base64 encoded byte string of a resume file from Google Storage with the code below.

```
storage_client = storage.Client(project=[MYPROJECT])
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket([MYBUCKET])
blob = bucket.blob([MYKEY])
resume_file = blob.download_as_string()

resume_file = str(base64.b64encode(resume_file))[2:-1]
```

I send that as part of my request parameters like so:

```
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(signed_jwt),
           'content-type': 'application/json'}

params = {'inputtype': 'file',
           'resume': resume_file}
    
response = requests.get(HOST, headers=headers, params=params)
```

However, I get the following error:

> Error 413 (Request Entity Too Large)
>
> Your client issued a request that was too large
>
> That's all we know

App Engine has a file size limit of 32MB. However, my file is only 24KB.  How can I fix this error?

Comment: Can you show the code?

Comment: I have edited the original post @DanCornilescu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to change my application to accept POST requests instead of GET requests.

Previously, I was sending the resume as a parameter.  I'm now sending it as data:

```
payload = json.dumps({
            'inputtype': inputtype,
            'resume': inputresume
          })

response = requests.post(HOST, headers=headers, data=payload)
```

I am using Flask.  Previously I was reading in the params using:

```
request.args.get('resume')
```

I changed it to:

```
request.get_json().get('resume')
```

This is an extension of the question/answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25299681/google-app-engine-413-error-request-entity-too-large)